# How to get index of string that have similar name in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, dictionary

i have a question about to get index of string.Below is my code :-

```
string x= "My name is Cinderella. #disneyworld #cinderella #disney."; Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string> ();
Regex exp = new Regex (@"#[A-Za-z0-9]\w+");
MatchCollection matches = exp.Matches (text.ToLower());
for (int i = 0; (i < matches.Count); i++)
{
 var str = matches [i].Value;
 var index = text.IndexOf (str, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
 dict.Add (index, str);
}
```

i get an error when  adding dict because same key is added. for value #disneyworld & #disney. how can i get index for #disney?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the index of the match from the `Match` object as follows

```
foreach(Match match in matches) {
    int index = match.Index;
    dict.Add(index, match.Value);
}
```

Here is the link to the [`Match.Index`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation